# Using cordova-plugin-file on Android 7 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to use the current version in a Cordova App. I'm building this App on my Android 7 device and the method to create a .txt file deos not work.

My Question is whether it is possible that the method to create a file is not working because of the reason that the cordova-plugin-file is not released for android 7, yet?

Comment: could you post the plugin you are using? 
In my experience with cordova apps, the majority plugins  does not support android 7.

Comment: i'm using this plugin: [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html) in the Version 4.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [mirror](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) repository of your plugin, they don´t build it to the android version 7.
What i recommend you to do: open a issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%29%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20File%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20summary%20ASC%2C%20updatedDate%20DESC) to notify them and get your problem solved!